# How to stream elements of nested array in mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in a mongoDB Database and the elements within that collection have this structure:

```
{  _id: ..., name: ....., list: [] }
```

I would like to retrieve one of the documents within the collection and iterate over the elements in the `list` property.

Something like this:

```
  const id = ...
  const cursor = collection.find({ _id: id });

  cursor.forEach(
    async (document) => {
      // Stream each element in the "list" array individually
      for (const listItem of document.list) {
        // Emit each listItem as a separate stream item
        console.log('Streamed item:', listItem);
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error while streaming list elements:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Streaming of list elements completed.');
      }
    }
  )
```

However, I get a warning that `cursor.forEach` is deprecated. What's another way of doing this?